# is invokeAll() a blocking call in java 7

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();

callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 1";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 2";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 3";
    }
});

List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);

for(Future<String> future : futures){
    System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
}
```

For this code piece. My question is "is invokeAll() a blocking call "?
I mean, when code ran to invokeAll() line, are we bloking there to wait for all result been generated?

Comment: No. The `future.get()` blocks.

Comment: @Slanec Actually, I think invokeAll is block, not returning until all the tasks in the list have either completed, failed or cancelled, *"Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete"* - while I'll admit it's ambiguous, I've used this in the past for this specific reason, "run this bunch of stuff, and let me know when you're done"

Comment: Luckily, we can easily try it out.

Comment: It looks as invokeAll  is blocking. I tried different execution services and I can see that my tasks always get completed before invokeAll is finished. It looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their
> status and results when all complete. **Future.isDone() is true for each
> element of the returned list.** Note that a completed task could have
> terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of
> this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while
> this operation is in progress.

Futures can only be done when execution is finished, therefore this method can only return when the tasks have been executed.

That it can throw an InterruptedException is also indicative of a blocking action.

Looking at the implementation of `invokeAll` in `java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService` (comment inline):

```
// from OpenJDK source; GPL-2.0-with-classpath-exception
public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
    throws InterruptedException {
    if (tasks == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    ArrayList<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<T>>(tasks.size());
    boolean done = false;
    try {
        for (Callable<T> t : tasks) {
            RunnableFuture<T> f = newTaskFor(t);
            futures.add(f);
            execute(f);
        }
        for (int i = 0, size = futures.size(); i < size; i++) {
            Future<T> f = futures.get(i);
            if (!f.isDone()) {
                try {
                    f.get(); // <== *** BLOCKS HERE ***

                } catch (CancellationException ignore) {
                } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
        done = true;
        return futures;
    } finally {
        if (!done)
            for (int i = 0, size = futures.size(); i < size; i++)
                futures.get(i).cancel(true);
    }
}
```

In fact, looking at a reference implementation is what you generally should do in these cases when the Javadoc-Specese appears to be difficult to decipher. <sup>(with the caveat in mind that some implementation details are not part of the spec.)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You mean if the parent thread will wait for all the thread created using your `ExecutorService` invocation? Then answer is yes, parent thread will wait and once all threads are finished you will get the list of `Futures` object which will hold the result of each thread execution.

See below from [ExecutorService.invokeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their
>   status and results **when all complete**.

Comment: This might be twisting words, but couldn't that also be interpreted that all the futures only update their result-states once all tasks have finished even though the futures have been returned immediately?

Comment: @the8472 From the user perspective, as docs says - `Future` list will be returned once all tasks are finished. From JVM internal perspective, yes each task will return its result and `Future` list will keep on building up and final list will only be returned once all tasks are done.

Comment: I meant from a user perspective if you're reading the docs incorrectly: *"Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures; holding their status and results when all complete."*. i.e. the internal state of the futures all updating atomically but the list being returned immediately. At least that's what I think where OP's confusion comes from.

Comment: @the8472 Sorry, I am not able to understand your point, could you elaborate?

Comment: alternative interpretation of javadoc: 1. awaitAll returns list of unresolved futures immediately.  2. futures *update their status and results [all at once] when all complete*. I.e. that the sentence is to be taken as some atomicity guarantee or something. It's a strange reading. But *i think* that's what OP might have seen in there.

Comment: @the8472 Interpretations are tightly coupled with the readers. What OP wanted to know and what docs says is the fact that parent thread will wait until all tasks are finished (completed successfully or abrupted due to exception).

Comment: Not when the _threads_ are finished: It's when the _tasks_ are finished.  Most ExecutorService implementations are thread pools, and the whole point of a thread pool is to _not_ let threads die when they complete any given task, but to re-use them for the next task.

Answer (score 0):

InvokeAll method blocks till all the tasks are completed and list of futures are returned,
**Solution:**
If we don't want this to happen and continue with execution of program ,we can  Loop through the tasks and pass it to Submit method of ExecutorService and add it to the List of Future Objects

```
    ExecutorService es=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    List<SampleClassimplementingCallable<String>> tasks=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Future<String>> futures=new  ArrayList<>();
    for(SampleClassimplementingCallable<String> s:tasks)
    {   
        //This Won't Block the Calling Thread and We will get the list of futures
        futures.add(es.submit(s));
    }
    
    
    However, When the Futures are retrieved from the list and get method is called on indivual future object ,then the thread is blocked.
```